# Sensitivity analysis of outliers in correlation

Tags: r

Suppose I have two vectors and their correlation:

```
set.seed(123)    
x<-c(rnorm(19), 99.1)
y<-rnorm(20, 5, 8)
cor(x,y)
#[1] -0.0721101
cor(x[1:19], y[1:19])
#[1] -0.0331376
```

My question is how to measure the `sensitivity` (like using `p.value`) for the correlation between `x` and `y` in terms of the potential outlier.

Comment: If all data points are valid, you shouldn't remove an outlier.

Comment: Also, define what you mean by "sensitivity" here. What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package `outliers` to detect outliers:

```
outliers::grubbs.test(c(x,y))



Grubbs test for one outlier

data:  c(x, y)
G = 5.84030, U = 0.10299, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: highest value 99.1 is an outlier
```